# How to check if toggle function show item?

Tags: javascript, toggle

I have this code ...

```
<div class="btn1">Button</div>
<div class="text1">Some text</div>
...
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".btn1").click(function(){
        $(".text1").toggle();
    });
});

<div class="block2">Some text 2</div>
```

I want to hide ".block2" when toggle function show ".text1" and show ".block2" when ".text1" is hidden. How can I do that? I hope my question is clear. Thanks for answers.

Comment: share your code in a fiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1) see this http://jsfiddle.net/a6kqvLj8/
>
> Just make the second block `diaplay:none`, and do the same operations
>   on it

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".btn1").click(function() {
    $(".text1").toggle();
    $(".block2").toggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn1">Button</div>
<div class="text1">Some text</div>

<div class="block2" style='display:none;'>Some text 2</div>
```

> 2)  Or if you want the both blocks to be visible at first, and the
>   start toggling on click, you can do this:
>   http://jsfiddle.net/a6kqvLj8/1/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".btn1").click(function() {
    $(".text1").toggle();
    if ($(".text1").css('display') == 'none') {
      $(".block2").css('display', 'block');
    } else {
      $(".block2").css('display', 'none');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn1">Button</div>
<div class="text1">Some text</div>

<div class="block2">Some text 2</div>
```

Comment: Thanks ... your solution is very elegant and perfect for me. (just to add another toggle